# GPUImage: Keep Recording movie crashed 'Unable to create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context'

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

When I keep trying to record the video and then finish recording, I get a crash like this

```
FirstGPUImage[768:179067] *** Terminating app due to uncaught 
exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to create 
an OpenGL ES 2.0 context. The GPUImage framework requires OpenGL ES 2.0 
support to work.'
```

[A screenshot of the error in XCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLq44.png)

I don't know if there is a problem with my own code or GPUImageMovieWrite, so I would like to ask you why!

This is my code:

```
func startTest(){
    mCamera.addAudioInputsAndOutputs()//避免录制第一帧黑屏
    let name = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    videoUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())folder_demo\(name).mp4")
    unlink(videoUrl?.path)
    var size = CGSize(width: 480, height: 640)
    movieWriter = GPUImageMovieWriter(movieURL:videoUrl, size:size )
    movieWriter?.assetWriter.movieFragmentInterval = kCMTimeInvalid
    movieWriter?.encodingLiveVideo = true
    movieWriter?.setHasAudioTrack(true, audioSettings: nil)
    ifFilter.addTarget(movieWriter)
    self.mCamera.audioEncodingTarget = self.movieWriter
    self.movieWriter?.startRecording()
    liveTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTest), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

   @objc func  updateTest(){
    weak var ws = self
    movieWriter?.finishRecording(completionHandler: {
        ws?.startTest()
        print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following method：
Everytime when you want to finish record ,you need remove all target from write :

```
/// finish 
///
/// - Parameter finish: block
func liveFinishRecord(finish:@escaping ()->()){
    ifFilter.removeTarget(movieWriter)
    movieWriter?.finishRecording(completionHandler: {
        finish()
    })
}
```